# Plotting two lists as a line does not work

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have functions that create two lists of numbers.

Using matplotlip I am able to plot these two lists as points, but when I try to plot as a line (formatter: `'-'`), the resulting graph is just blank.

What is wrong here?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

var = "1.460.362.021.640.560.361.010.520.240.342.680.622.670.850.411.051.880.030.970.502.194.762.872.040.262.140.601.350.470.150.111.010.070.020.561.490.631.281.510.131.611.271.150.521.180.722.080.831.350.761.321.990.620.353.480.541.131.910.130.801.991.012.350.470.162.421.231.921.050.231.871.020.130.750.740.060.310.061.041.301.530.421.662.783.151.931.011.971.790.952.090.110.931.231.370.761.091.595.040.322.330.171.930.310.100.161.510.340.231.202.580.301.481.610.503.840.120.451.160.00"
rain = []
year = [1895]
e = 1895
i = 0

def rainv(i,var,rain):
    while i < 477:
        a = float(var[0 + i :4 + i])
        i = i + 4
        rain.append(a)
        if i  >= 476:
            return rain

def theyear(year, e):
    while e < 2015:
            e = e + 1
            year.append(e)
            if e == 2015:
                return year

rainv(i,var,rain)
theyear(year,e)
print(rain)
print(year)

plt.plot([year],[rain], '-')
plt.axis([1885,2014, 0,6])
plt.show()
```

Comment: When I execute your code an error is shown: _ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension_. Maybe you should work on that.

Comment: Yeah i have that problem worked out, it wants to be put brackets around [year],[rain] in my plot function. This is also a mystery to me. Regardless i fixed it in my question.

Comment: You should rather leave the code in the question as is and add an answer with the fixed code and ideally also an explanation of the error you had (or close/delete the question as simple typo error or alike...). To indicate the issue as resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have accidentally passed a **list of list** to the plot as parameters,

'year' and 'rain' are already in form of a list, so just change the following line

```
plt.plot([year],[rain], '-')
```

to

```
plt.plot(year,rain, '-')
```

**Some more explanation:-**

by using [year], the list passed is something like this :-

```
[[1897,...., 2015]]
```

but you need to pass something like

```
[1897,...., 2015]
```

also make sure to keep x and y having same dimension. In the code you have provided, they are not, length of one list is 119, while other is 121

cheers